# Kill the Menu

Tags: vmware-workstation

Downloaded and installed VM Player 3.0.
two questions?

1.) Can I use Windows SMS to install the player on a users computer? If yes. Were can I find this information?

2.) Is there a hack of fix that allows me to kill/remove/hide the Player menus? I don't want the user to build new VM machines, just run the one want them to run.

Not allowed to use Workstation or Ace to dist the vm

Thanks

Comment: 1. No idea, but I know there are sites that gather and publish info on publishing many different applications, I'm sure VM Player is popular enough to have a few entries.

2. For your stated objective, you shouldn't need that. If it's Player, then they shouldn't be able to build new VM machines. That's why it's the free product. Now, they can Open other VMs, play with their VM network settings, etc - but you couldn't prevent that very easily even if the menu was hidden.

Comment: @mfinni You can build new VM's with Player V3 see the first feature listed: http://www.vmware.com/support/player30/doc/releasenotes_player3.html It's still much more limited than Workstation but creating VM's is no longer a problem.

Comment: Well holy crap. I need to stay a little more current. Thanks, Helvick!

Comment: About 2) (besides the answers about it that may actually work) that's really what Ace is for so... it seems a bit much to ask from the free Player.

Answer (score 1):

In re #2:  The usual Windows method would be to give the user a shortcut to the virtual machine file and make VM Player the default "open with..." application.  This should bypass any opening dialogs or menus and start the VM straight away.

Comment: +1 I saw something about if you do this or rather pass the vmx file on the command line - the player settings will be disabled...

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, sure. Here are the commands line to deploy the package (for version 2.0 but would work for 3.0):
http://www.appdeploy.com/packages/detail.asp?id=1086

In short, you can do a direct silent install through classic command line arguments